# Exists[ ] statement inside RegionPlot[ ] too hard to resolve?

Tags: plotting, regions

I've got a very complicated existential boolean expression, call it $\exists x: condition$, involving variables $p, q, $ and $x$. Is there a way to plot the region in which this statement holds without running resolve on it first? `RegionPlot[Exists[x, condition], {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}]` does not seem to be doing the job...

Comment: Hard to say without a more concrete example. Why don't you try sharing the statement here for a start?

Comment: This example works Ok. `RegionPlot[Resolve@Exists[x, p < x < q], {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: but you are using Resolve there, right? Or do I misunderstand the @ notation?

Comment: @MarcoB: the statement fills a couple of pages of paper; I could compress it and share but I thought I was asking a more general question about how to plot existential statements in general without using resolve?

Comment: @PortMeadow Of course. `Exists[ ]` won't do much on its own

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: Let me phrase it this way. Surely what region plot does is evaluate the boolean condition. Is there a way to tell it to do the resolve after fixing the values for p and q? That way, the resolve is only in one dimension rather than three...

Comment: I am not sure about what your question is. But perhaps `f[p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := Resolve@Exists[x, p < x < q];
RegionPlot[f[p, q], {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}]`

Comment: That is an excellent idea & might be the solution :)

Comment: @PortMeadow If you think that Belisarius's comment solves your problem, perhaps you would consider posting a self-answer. These are highly encourages in StackExchange, and they may help somebody else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved by combining delayed evaluation, `ParallelTable` and `ArrayPlot`:

```
f[p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := Resolve@Exists[x, p < x < q];
table = ParallelTable[f[p,q],{p,0,1,0.1},{q,0,1,0.1}];
ArrayPlot[table /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}, DataReversed -> True]
```

This exploits the fact that a resolve in inequalities with just one variable is much quicker than for inequalities with multiple variables. It also uses `ParallelTable` in order to further speed up calculations. We end up using `ArrayPlot` instead of `RegionPlot`, which only produces a pixelated approximation to the area, but it is better than nothing.

[Thank you to @Dr.belisarius for the idea to use delayed evaluation]